# Login form in Laravel is giving the error 419 Page Expired

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

It used to work somoothly, then I added Sociallite and then it some point it broke the default login with email and password.
Now every time I login with username and password I get the error "`419 Page Expired`" and it's literally diving me crazy because I have tried everything, with no luck.

View login.blade.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                @error('email')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                @error('password')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ __('Login') }}
                </button>
                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                    </a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>    
    </form>
```

Route web.php:

```
Route::post('login', [
        'as' => '',
        'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'
    ]);
```

I searched the web and found some ppl talking about clearing cash, clearing cookies, checking cash and storage permissions, clearing SESSION_DOMAIN and I did all, but it's still the same.

Please anyone is still facing such issue in Larvel 7?

Comment: have you tried adding csrf as a meta tag as well ?

Comment: Can you share validations rules for login?

Comment: Where to add the meta tag exactly?

Comment: @maki10 where can I find the validation rules? I'm not sure I understand what are they

Comment: Hey can you try to change route, i.e `default.login` .. What is maybe happened is that login route is tight couplet to Socialite

Comment: @Lamar https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token